# Java unit test for void methods

Tags: java, unit-testing

First of all I would like to apologise about my language skill, but my mother language isn't english.

I have got a little source code, which is:

```
public void hello(List l){    
    switch (l.get(0) {    
    case "hello":    
         System.out.println("Hello!");    
    case "world":    
        System.out.println("World");    
        break;    
    }    
}
```

And I have to write a unit test, which can testing about this code. But my skill is not enough about it. Could somebody help me please? Some example or book or something. I don't know how can I starting it!

I am appreciate.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not obviously test if the method returns correct value if it is 'void'. However you can test whether it throws any exception or not. If you want to test the computation you need to refactor the code such that the computation is a separate method that returns a value.

Comment: -1: Your advices are very misleading. OP **does not need** to refactor to *method returning value* in order to test (as other answerers have clearly shown). On top of that, testing whether method *doesn't throw* makes little to no sense as it provides no information on what the method actually does, rendering such test useless.

Comment: If OP can modify the code then re factoring is the correct approach rather than capturing output stream etc.

Answer (score 2):

You should break up your code into two methods - one prints the results of the second, and the second can be easily unit tested.

Comment: Can you write a simple code about your example?? I don't understand 100% percent what are you thinking! :/
I am not waiting the solution, just another example which can I use to my problame.

Comment: public void a(String i) { System.out.println(b(i)); } // not unit testable
public String b(String i) { if ("a".equals(i")) { return "b"; } else { return "c"; } } // unit testabkle

Comment: So if I understand First of all I have to change my source code about your example. And after I have to unit testing the new source code?

Answer (score 2):

You could test the method by launching a new JVM and calling code that calls this then capturing the output, but...

Simpler to refactor the code so you *can* test it: Extract a method that returns a String, leaving a wrapper method that prints the result, but you test the extracted method.

Answer (score 1):

To be able to test this method, you'd have to be able to tell what has been printed to System.out. You would thus have to replace System.out by another stream, writing in memory, so that you can inspect the content of the stream after the method has been called. This is doable, but not so easy.

You would make your method more reusable, and more testable, if instead of printing to System.out, it returned a String instead. You couls also pass an additional argument, of type PrintStream, where the method would write, which would make a test easier by passing a PrintStream which would write to a byte array.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the outputstream to a mock one like this (using Mockito).

```
PrintStream mockStream = Mockito.mock(PrintStream.class);
PrintStream original = System.out;
System.out = mockStream;

//call your method here:
hello(myList);

//check if your method has done its job correctly
Mockito.verify(mockStream).println("Hello!");
//clean up
System.out = orig;
```

Also, don't forget to put a `break` after your first case or it will fall through and print the second time as well.

Comment: Thanks! So if I undersand well I have to put my source code that place //call your method here ??? Or this code which you wrote me is can testing unit test, or what? Sorry but I am not understand totally! :/